# How to get R Output into csv file?

Tags: r, csv, twitter

The answer might be easy but I am stuck:

I use Twitter API 1.1 to get tweets of a certain account. By using the following function

```
user <- getUser("xxx")
userTimeline(user, n=300, maxID=NULL, sinceID=NULL, includeRts=FALSE)
```

I get about 150 tweets back. It looks like that:

```
[[125]]
[1] "AlexSalmond: Many thanks to @welovehistory carpentry &amp; joinery apprentice    Hannah Ross for the table she's built for Bute House http://t.co/1CnuACirLC"

[[126]]
[1] "AlexSalmond: Well done to all involved in #ArmedForcesDay &amp; #BannockburnLive â€“ making Stirlingâ€™s Big Weekend a massive success http://t.co/ho3Az1O9cF"

[[127]]
[1] "AlexSalmond: Enjoyed conversation and public Q&amp;A with @DerekBateman2 last week â€“ you can listen here: http://t.co/alCkf14zij #IndyRef"
```

How can I save these data to a csv file?

By using `write.csv` it gives me the following mistake:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
cannot coerce class "structure("user", package = "twitteR")" to a data.frame
```

Comment: Coerce it into a data.frame or a matrix. `write.table` or `write.csv` should work. Alternatively, you can `writeLines` to write each list element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a function in the twitteR package to take that list and create a dataframe out of it...
twListToDF

```
user <- getUser("xxx")
data <- userTimeline(user, n=300, maxID=NULL, sinceID=NULL, includeRts=FALSE) 
write.csv(twListToDF(data), file="something.csv")
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That's a really nice solution and it's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your data into a dataframe. It seems like your data is in the form of a list.

If your twitter data is named **twitterList**,

```
    data <- data.frame(cbind(twitterList))
```

data will now contain 150 observations (if your twitterList has 150 tweetlists).

Now you can write **data** :

```
 write.table(data, "filename.csv", row.names=FALSE, sep=",")
```

This will write your data as a csv file into your working directory. Or else choose your own location and filename and it will save the csv file into that location you defined accordingly.